# Avoid data type selection in VBA when building using QueryTables.Add from .CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am struggling to correctly read the CSV file. In the file I have values that look like this:

```txt
21-01
21-02
21-03
21-04
...
```

When I try to use the QueryTables.Add function (code shown below), I get this output:

```txt
21.01
21.02
21.03
21.04
21.05
21.06
21.07
21.08
21.09
21.10
21.11
21.12
21-13
21-14
...
```

The data shown with "." in them are always formatted as own formatting, though it thinks it is a date in the form of "21.1.2024". When I format them as text it shows the dates numeric values. When Excel runs out of month it formats other cells correctly, until it finds another set of values that look like date. Cells with "-" are formatted by excel as "General" formatting, those with date as my own formatting.

When I use the build in function for creating the table from .CSV, I get the option of "Data type detection" to "Do not detect data types" and that does exactly what I need when done manually. I need to emulate this function in my automation for the VBA. Is that possible? If so, how?

```
Sub Data_Import()

Dim Exp_File_Name As String
'...

Exp_File_Name = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Provide Text or CSV File:")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Exp_File_Name, _
                            Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1"))
         .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
         .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
         .Refresh
    End With

'...

End Sub
```

I tried to parse it using something similar to this:

```
 .TextFileColumnDataTypes = _ 
 Array(xlTextFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat)
```

But it did not help. It seems that the moment Excel reads the files it immediately replaces "-" with ".".

Here is the CSV that I am trying to parse:

```
[MAIN_YN];[ACTIVE_YN];[ARCHIVED_YN];[CAN_ADD_TO_BASKET_YN];[CODE]
;1;0;1;21-01
;1;0;1;21-02
;1;0;1;21-03
;1;0;1;21-04
;1;0;1;21-05
;1;0;1;21-06
;1;0;1;21-07
;1;0;1;21-08
;1;0;1;21-09
;1;0;1;21-10
;1;0;1;21-11
;1;0;1;21-12
;1;0;1;21-13
;1;0;1;21-14
;1;0;1;21-15
;1;0;1;21-16
;1;0;1;21-17
;1;0;1;21-18
;1;0;1;21-19
;1;0;1;21-20
;1;0;1;21-21
;1;0;1;21-22
;1;0;1;21-23
;1;0;1;21-24
;1;0;1;21-25
;1;0;1;21-26
;1;0;1;21-27
;1;0;1;21-28
;1;0;1;21-29
;1;0;1;21-30
;1;0;1;21-31
;1;0;1;21-32
;1;0;1;21-33
;1;0;1;21-35
;1;0;1;21-36
;1;0;1;21-37
;1;0;1;21-38
;1;0;1;21-39
;1;0;1;21-40
;1;0;1;21-41
;1;0;1;21-42
;1;0;1;21-43
;1;0;1;21-44
;1;0;1;21-45
;1;0;1;21-46
;1;0;1;21-47
;1;0;1;21-48
;1;0;1;21-49
;1;0;1;21-50
;1;0;1;21-51
;1;0;1;21-52
;1;0;1;21-53
;1;0;1;21-54
;1;0;1;21-55
;1;0;1;21-56
;1;0;1;21-57
;1;0;1;21-58
;1;0;1;22-01
;1;0;1;22-02
;1;0;1;22-03
;1;0;1;22-04
;1;0;1;22-05
;1;0;1;22-06
;1;0;1;22-07
;1;0;1;22-08
;1;0;1;22-09
;1;0;1;22-10
;1;0;1;22-11
;1;0;1;22-12
;1;0;1;22-13
;1;0;1;22-14
;1;0;1;22-15
;1;0;1;22-16
;1;0;1;22-17
;1;0;1;22-18
;1;0;1;22-19
;1;0;1;22-20
;1;0;1;22-21
;1;0;1;22-22
;1;0;1;22-23
;1;0;1;22-24
;1;0;1;22-25
;1;0;1;22-26
;1;0;1;22-27
;1;0;1;22-28
;1;0;1;22-29
;1;0;1;22-30
;1;0;1;22-31
;1;0;1;22-32
;1;0;1;22-33
;1;0;1;22-34
;1;0;1;22-35
;1;0;1;22-36
;1;0;1;22-37
;1;0;1;22-38
;1;0;1;22-39
;1;0;1;22-40
;1;0;1;22-41
;1;0;1;22-42
;1;0;1;22-43
;1;0;1;22-44
;1;0;1;22-45
;1;0;1;22-46
;1;0;1;22-47
;1;0;1;22-48
;1;0;1;22-49
;1;0;1;22-50
;1;0;1;22-51
;1;0;1;22-52
;1;0;1;22-53
;1;0;1;22-54
;1;0;1;22-55
;1;0;1;22-56
;1;0;1;22-57
;1;0;1;22-58
;1;0;1;22-59
;1;0;1;22-60
;1;0;1;22-61
;1;0;1;22-62
;1;0;1;22-63
;1;0;1;22-64
;1;0;1;22-65
;1;0;1;22-67
;1;0;1;22-68
;1;0;1;22-69
;1;0;1;22-70
;1;0;1;22-71
;1;0;1;22-72
;1;0;1;22-73
;1;0;1;22-74
;1;0;1;22-75
;1;0;1;22-76
;1;0;1;22-77
;1;0;1;22-78
;1;0;1;22-79
;1;0;1;22-80
;1;0;1;22-81
;1;0;1;22-82
;1;0;1;22-83
;1;0;1;22-84
;1;0;1;22-85
;1;0;1;22-86
;1;0;1;22-87
;1;0;1;22-88
;1;0;1;22-89
;1;0;1;22-90
;1;0;1;22-91
;1;0;1;22-92
;1;0;1;22-93
;1;0;1;22-94
;1;0;1;27-02
;1;0;1;27-03
;1;0;1;27-05
;1;0;1;27-06
;1;0;1;27-09
;1;0;1;27-10
;1;0;1;27-12
;1;0;1;27-13
;1;0;1;27-14
;1;0;1;27-21
;1;0;1;27-22
;1;0;1;27-23
;1;0;1;27-24
;1;0;1;27-25
;1;0;1;27-26
;1;0;1;27-27
;1;0;1;27-28
;1;0;1;27-29
;1;0;1;27-30
;1;0;0;9918995604706
;1;0;1;27-32
;1;0;1;27-33
;1;0;1;27-34
;1;0;1;27-35
;1;0;1;29-10
;1;0;1;29-11
;1;0;1;29-12
;1;0;1;29-13
;1;0;1;29-14
;1;0;1;29-15
;1;0;1;29-16
;1;0;1;29-17
;1;0;1;29-18
;1;0;1;29-19
;1;0;1;29-20
;1;0;1;29-21
;1;0;1;29-22
;1;0;1;29-23
;1;0;1;29-24
;1;0;1;29-25
;1;0;1;29-26
;1;0;1;29-27
;1;0;1;29-28
;1;0;1;29-29
;1;0;1;29-30
;1;0;1;29-31
;1;0;1;29-32
;1;0;1;29-33
;1;0;1;29-34
;1;0;1;29-35
;1;0;1;29-36
;1;0;1;29-37
;1;0;1;29-38
;1;0;1;29-39
;1;0;1;29-40
;1;0;1;29-41
;1;0;1;29-42
;1;0;1;29-43
;1;0;1;48-94
```

Comment: Maybe look at specifying `TextFileColumnDataTypes` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfilecolumndatatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `TextFileColumnDataTypes` worked for me: values were imported as-is without any date conversions.

If you only want to keep all columns imported as text, but you're not sure how many columns you'll be importing, you can provide a large array of `xlTextFormat` values to `TextFileColumnDataTypes` and it will ignore any "extra" elements in the array.

```
Sub Data_Import()
    Dim Exp_File_Name

    Exp_File_Name = "C:\Temp\info.txt" 'has a single column of values

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Exp_File_Name, _
                            Destination:=[A1])
         .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
         .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
         .TextFileColumnDataTypes = AllTextFormat()
         .Refresh
    End With
End Sub

'return an array of `xlTextFormat` values
Function AllTextFormat()
    Dim arr(0 To 100), i As Long
    For i = 0 To 100
        arr(i) = xlTextFormat
    Next i
    AllTextFormat = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. Here is a sample part of the .CSV that I can share, maybe you can test whether the issue shows up as well:

[MAIN_YN];[ACTIVE_YN];[ARCHIVED_YN];[CAN_ADD_TO_BASKET_YN];[CODE]
;1;0;1;21-01
;1;0;1;21-02
;1;0;1;21-03
;1;0;1;21-04
;1;0;1;21-05
;1;0;1;21-06
;1;0;1;21-07
;1;0;1;21-08
;1;0;1;21-09
;1;0;1;21-10
;1;0;1;21-11
;1;0;1;21-12
;1;0;1;21-13
;1;0;1;21-14
;1;0;1;21-15
;1;0;1;21-16
;1;0;1;21-17
;1;0;1;21-18
;1;0;1;21-19
;1;0;1;21-20
;1;0;1;21-21
;1;0;1;21-22

Comment: Please share as a file or add formatted to your question - it's not obvious exactly how that looks in your file.  Also - did you add one format per column inside `Array()`?

Comment: Specifying a type for each column works fine for me.  See edit above based on your sample.  Use whatever datatype is appropriate - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype

Comment: Okay, I added it to the original post. I am new to StackOverflow. I did not add it for each column I admit, but the .CSV will not be static- order of columns as well as the amount will be changing overtime, so coding it by fixed coordinates is not really an option. I would need to apply the "Do not detect data types" thingy to the whole QuerryTable. Maybe I am going around it wrong and I might use a different method?

Comment: It's difficult to have a fully-dynamic way of importing random datasets while preserving the intended data types, without knowing something about the incoming data...  You could maybe import the file and check the headers, if they would tell you which datatype was needed for each column, then re-import using those types in the `TextFileColumnDataTypes` array.

Comment: Well I know that all the data that I will need will always be in the first 20 columns, I need them all imported exactly as-is, formatting does not matter because I will edit the data further later. It can all be imported as text or all as general, whatever format will keep original values exactly

Comment: Try the edit above. If all you need to do is import everything as text then supply an array of `xlTextFormat` values with at least the same number of elements as the number of columns in your file.  Extra values in the array seem to be ignored.

Comment: That solution solved even more issues that I was facing including this one. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Good to hear we managed to figure out a solution.